# Let a matrix be non-diagonalizable and not nilpotent then $T^k$ is not diagonalizable as well.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb C$. Let $T$ be an operator on $V$ which is not diagonalizable and not nilpotent. Then $T^k$ is not diagonalizable for any $k$ positive integer.(Prove or give counterexample-ish question)

I try to use Cayley Hamilton theorem that the char polynomial is satisfies the operator but couldnot go nowhere. Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: edited it       ........

Answer (score 2):

Hint: try a $3 \times 3$ matrix with two linearly independent eigenvectors.

Answer (score 1):

Matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0 \end{pmatrix}$ is a counterexample. It is not diagonalizable because it has a Jordan $2\times 2$ block, non-nilpotent because it has eigenvalue 1 and its square is
$\begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0 \end{pmatrix}$ which is diagonal.

Remark: The statement in the OP is   true iff there exists a non-nilpotent Jordan block of size $>1$, i.e., a Jordan block of size $\ge 2$ with non-zero eigenvalue.